# Can i replace a 0.75A 76V SMD fuse with a 1.25A 250V one?

Tags: surface-mount, fuses

It's for an LCD TV inverter. The seller said I could even use a thin wire. I'm not sure about that that's why I still bought it but I want to make sure before putting it in. It seems that it's for powering the PWM controller.

Comment: A thin wire does not substitute for a fuse at all. It is extremely bad practise, especially since "thin" is somewhat arbitrary and could allow for current that could damage the device permanently.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace a 0.75A fuse with a 1.25A one, but it would not be safe to do so. The designer of the TV specified 0.75A for protection. Fitting a 1.25A fuse could allow excessive current to flow in a fault situation, and that may not be safe.

If the 0.75A fuse is blowing frequently, and when it shouldn't (no fault), then maybe a 1.0A fuse could be fitted. Do not fit a thin wire!

Using a 250V fuse in place of a 76V one is fine. Using a non-SMD fuse in place of an SMD one is also OK.

Comment: Just an addition: The specified rating usually is two to three times higher than the expected permanent current. So, a really high current has been drawn to blow the fuse. With 1.25A, you shift the factor to 3-4x.